# Can the contents of a table cell overflow vertically?

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, language-lawyer, css-tables

A table cell may have content that overflows, as explained in in the [fixed table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout):

> Any cell that has content that overflows uses the ['overflow'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)
>   property to determine whether to clip the overflow content.

But can that overflow be vertical? The [table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) says

> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by
>   the content.

So if I understand correctly, it shouldn't be possible. But I can make it happen on Firefox:

```css
table {
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Foo</div>
      <div>Bar</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the spec, or is this a bug?

Comment: Why are you specifying `display` property for `table` and `td` elements?

Comment: Because first they weren't tabular elements, only styled as tables. Then I used tabular elements but forgot to remove the styles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[§17.5.3 Table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) also says

> CSS 2.1 does not define how the height of table cells and table rows is calculated when their height is specified using percentage values.

And it really shows — you get wildly different results in various browsers.

Here's what it looks like on IE:

[image]

And on Chrome:

[image]

From what I can tell:

- Chrome is calculating the minimum height required by having both `div` elements at their minimum height required by their contents, sizing the table accordingly, and ignoring the `height: 100%` declaration on the `div` elements.
- IE and Firefox size the table in much the same way as Chrome, but then they choose to apply the `height: 100%` on the `div` elements instead. This results in the overflow you describe.
- IE does something funky where it expands the first `div` upwards, seemingly ignoring baselines altogether despite the fact that the `div` elements are block-level, not inline-level.

Since this is undefined behavior, particularly the kind that deals with percentage heights, it's hard to say if any of the browsers are either correct or wrong in this specific situation. I suspect you're more likely, though still not guaranteed, to get a satisfactory answer to your original question by specifying fixed heights on your table cells instead.

Comment: Feel free to modify the original code in your question if you'd like, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I understood that only the computed `height` was undefined, but the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells was well defined, so the height of the table row would be implementation-dependent but still big enough to wrap the content. I guess they should clarify what exactly is undefined.

Comment: @Oriol: In this case, both the table cells and the divs have percentage heights - this is a cyclic dependency which can never be resolved except by ignoring or not updating one of the values. Chrome chooses to ignore it on the divs, IE and Firefox choose to expand the divs to match the height of the td but not the td to match the height of the divs, because if they updated the td then the divs would have to be updated again... ad nauseum.